# Are Erlang -callbacks to be invoked only through MFA functions (apply/3, spawn/3, ...)? (Custom Behaviors HOWTO)

Tags: callback, erlang, erlang-otp

That's my suspicion as this simple code

```
-module(simple_server).
-export( [sayHello/0] ).

-callback say(Num :: term()) -> term().

sayHello() ->
    io:fwrite( "Hello 1: ~p\n", [ say(1) ]) ,
    io:fwrite( "Hello 2: ~p\n", [ say(2) ]) .
```

fails to be compiled:

```
$ erlc simple_server.erl
simple_server.erl:7: function say/1 undefined
simple_server.erl:8: function say/1 undefined
```

If that is the case, then this is not explicitly commented elsewhere:
[official docs](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#user-defined-behaviours), ["learn erlang"](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers#callback-to-the-future), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336854/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-erlang-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336854/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-erlang-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1 exposes the same problem without clearly showing how callbacks are supposed to be called.

Comment: In the accepted answer, the callback function is called as `CBM:fn(A)`.

Comment: @legoscia Yes. Then, the name of the module implementing the callback must be supplied to the generic code.

Comment: @legoscia If you are sure about the ways a generic module can call a callback (to be provided in the future) you could write an answer here to be accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the name of the callback module, which can be done through `apply` and `spawn`, but you can also make a simple call using a variable as the module name, e.g. `CallbackModule:say(1)`.

So you could do either:

```
sayHello(CallbackModule) ->
    io:fwrite( "Hello 1: ~p\n", [ CallbackModule:say(1) ]) ,
    io:fwrite( "Hello 2: ~p\n", [ CallbackModule:say(2) ]) .
```

or

```
sayHello(CallbackModule) ->
    io:fwrite( "Hello 1: ~p\n", [ apply(CallbackModule, say, [1]) ]) ,
    io:fwrite( "Hello 2: ~p\n", [ apply(CallbackModule, say, [2]) ]) .
```

Those two versions are equivalent.

Let's create a callback module implementing the `simple_server` behaviour:

```
-module(my_callback).
-behaviour(simple_server).
-export([say/1]).

say(N) ->
    {N, is, the, loneliest, number}.
```

Now we can call `simple_server:sayHello` with the module name as the argument:

```
> simple_server:sayHello(my_callback).
Hello 1: {1,is,the,loneliest,number}
Hello 2: {2,is,the,loneliest,number}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also prepared a simple explanatory example, including compile orders, which are very important (-pa flag).

Answer (score 1):

**HOWTO Erlang Custom Behaviors (template method pattern).**

-1. Write a generic module. Here, an algorithm is defined, but some steps (callback functions in Erlang nomenclature) are left for a future specific definition.

```
%% generic.erl   
-module(generic).
-export( [sayHello/1] ).

-callback say(Num :: term()) -> term(). %% future definition

%% generic algorithm: needs the reference to the provider module                                 
sayHello(ProviderModule) ->
  io:fwrite( "Hello 1: ~p\n", [ ProviderModule:say(1) ]) ,
  io:fwrite( "Hello 2: ~p\n", [ ProviderModule:say(2) ]) .
```

-2. Compile generic.erl

```
erlc generic.erl
```

-(3.) Try to write a provider (callback) module

```
%% callbacks1.erl (fails to implement say/1 callback)
-module( callbacks1 ).
-behaviour( generic ).
```

-(4.) Compile callbacks1.erl: **use -pa .** to say where generic.beam is. (Therefore, the expected warning about say/1 is issued).

```
erlc -pa . callbacks1.erl
callbacks1.erl:2: Warning: undefined callback function say/1 (behaviour 'generic')
```

(Note: If -pa is not given, you'll got this: "callbacks1.erl:2: Warning: behaviour generic undefined")

-3. Write a correct provider (callback) module.

```
%% callbacks2.erl
-module( callbacks2 ).
-behaviour( generic ).

-export( [say/1] ).

say(1) -> "good morning";
say(2) -> "bon jour";
say(_) -> "hi".
```

-4. Compile it

```
erlc -pa . callbacks2.erl
```

(Ok now).

-5. Write a main.erl to gather generic module with callback module.

```
%% main.erl
-module( main ).
-export( [main/0] ).

main() ->
    %% call the generic algorithm telling it what callback module to use
    generic:sayHello( callbacks2 ) 
    . % ()
```

-6. Compile and run main

```
erlc main.erl
erl -noshell -s main main -s init stop
```

We get:

```
Hello 1: "good morning"
Hello 2: "bon jour"
```